# Why does Visual Studio automatically converts or shows a number value as hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 and c#. In my project, when I store a number in an `int` variable. It shows a `hex` value in the debugger .How can I prevent this?

example :

```
int employeeID=12345;
```

After assigning the value here, `employeeID` is showing like 0x00003039:

```
public double GetSalary(int employeeID) //0x00003039
{
  /////
}
```

Comment: *"after assigning the value here employeeID showing 0x00003039"* Showing ***where***? And how exactly can a method's return type be both `void` and `double`?

Comment: do you mean when youre looking at `employeeID` with the debugger? (hex an dec is the same number just a different format)

Comment: employeeID variable showing 0x00003039 instead of 12345

Comment: why minus marking , this website is for problem solving platform, its not + and - . instead this you should give solution . if you didn't understand question then you should ask something regarding the question.

Comment: @JRB Please visit the help topics and read about up-/downvoting to understand why you receive up- or downvotes. In this special case you earn a downvote - not from me - just because you are showing fake and even not compilable code. Write your questions as precise and carefully as you expect the answers should be. Do you really want fake and not compilable code from us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click your `Watch` window.

Uncheck `Hexadecimal Display`

Just for the record: it is just a representation of the number. The actual format is not influenced by this.

[image]